# Is it 'ok' to have IFrame tags in RSS feeds?

Tags: rss, html, feeds, iframe

I ran my RSS feed through http://www.feedvalidator.org/ but it says:

> This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendations.
>
> line 83, column 0: content:encoded should not contain iframe tag (4 occurrences) [help]

I click on help and it sends me to http://www.feedvalidator.org/docs/warning/SecurityRisk.html . I don't see the IFrame tag on the list and cannot find out what I would replace it with if I took it out.

Is it harmless enough to leave as is or do I have to take it out?

<sub>I cannot seem to find any information to answer my question anywhere else.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it 'ok' to have IFrame tags in RSS feeds?

Well, as the error states, "interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved" ...if the `iframe` tag was removed.

This is understandable since the main purpose of the `iframe` tag is to import external content from another site - this could literally be anything. Why would you want/need to do this in an RSS feed? So, from a security point of view, RSS clients might block it. What is this `iframe` doing in the RSS feed? Any "content" should be embedded directly in the RSS feed, not dynamically inserted from another site - if that is what you are doing.

> Is it harmless enough to leave as is or do I have to take it out?

It might be harmless for your site, but as stated, some RSS feed readers may simply strip it out - so users won't see the content.

> what I would replace it with if I took it out.

Whatever content the `iframe` is *importing* should be embedded directly in the RSS feed.

**UPDATE (from comments):**

> This RSS feed is being creating by a WordPress blog page and on some of the blog posts we have YouTube videos.

There's not much you can do about embedding YouTube videos. To be honest, most(?) users will probably see it OK (Feedly certainly supports iframed YouTube videos) - but there maybe some users that won't. That is really all the "warning" you are seeing is about - making your content accessible to the largest possible audience. For these (few) users they should be able to follow a link to view the full post/video if they wish.

Comment: Thank you for responding! This RSS feed is being creating by a WordPress blog page and on some of the blog posts we have YouTube videos. So I would have to remove the videos in blog posts?

Comment: Ah OK. No, I would keep the videos in the posts - that is presumably useful content for your readers? There's not much you can do about embedding YouTube videos. Most(?) users will probably see it OK (Feedly certainly supports iframed YouTube videos) - but there maybe some users that won't (that is all the error you are seeing is about). For these users they should be able to follow a link to view the full post/video if they wish.

Comment: I have searched high and low on how to put it into a video tag but cannot find anything to change it to that will not show an error through the feed validator. I will just have to leave it. Thank you again!

Comment: TBH it doesn't look like that feed validator has been updated for "a while" (the latest entry on the "News" page is October 15, 2007)? If that's the case then that would simply pre-date the `video` tag. (?)